# Using javascript to read web page after full load

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs

Was trying to read the webpage using javascript & willing to run this from UNIX terminal using below, shell> node test_code.js.

test_code.js

```
const request = require('request');
request('http://mylocalurl.html', function (error, response, body) {
console.error('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

The above code does not wait for the web page to completely load(i.e, full load) & it gives the interim data which is inadequate.

Ask is to, check if we can make the request() function to wait for some time for the webpage to load until it pumps all data & later show all data within the response.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: *"The above code does not wait for the web page to completely load..."* What makes you think that? Although [the package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) is deprecated, it's been used a **lot** and I doubt it's fundamentally broken. Have you considered that perhaps the page in question **dynamically** loads content? (E.g., with JavaScript code?) `request` isn't going to run that code, for that you'd need a headless browser (there are a few for Node.js).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will check on this. Wanted to check with users as I am pretty much new to this.

Comment: "The above code does not wait for the web page to completely load..." What makes you think that? - Because, the response text after the call returned only the part of the web page content. But, per workflow, code has to wait for some more time & wait for the full page to load completely and then return the response. This was the expectation.

Comment: I suspect, again, that `request` **is** waiting for the full page returned by the initial request to the server. But then the page uses client-side JavaScript to add more content, which isn't all that uncommon.